# Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen zerlaufen und schmelzen?

Tags: meaning, difference, word-choice

Wo liegt der Unterschied zwischen zerlaufen und schmelzen?

> Das Eis ist in der Sonne zerlaufen/geschmolzen.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn etwas schmilzt, wird es aufgrund der Temperatur flüssig. Wie dauerhaft das ist, spielt dabei keine Rolle.

Verlaufen und zerlaufen kann etwas aber auch, weil es nass geworden und wasserlöslich ist, etwa die Farbe auf einem Aquarell. Bei anderen Flüssigkeiten natürlich aufgrund anderer Löslichkeiten.

Außerdem kann sich eine Menschenmenge zerlaufen, etwa nachdem ein Open-Air-Konzert zu Ende ist.

Mit verlaufen, welches ich ursprünglich in der Antwort verwendet habe, verhält es sich ebenso. Für einen absichtlicht erzeugten Verlauf würde ich aber immer verlaufen, nicht zerlaufen verwenden. 
Verlaufen kann sich aber auch ein Wanderer, der den richtigen Weg nicht findet. Dafür ist weder zerlaufen, nocht schmelzen das richtige Wort.

Einzig wenn man eine Substanz in einem festen Gefäß, etwa einer Eiswüfelform hat, kann die Substanz schmelzen ohne zu verlaufen oder zu zerlaufen. Wenn sie hart wird ist sie wieder in der ursprünglichen Form.

Comment: *Zerlaufen* war das Verb in der Frage. Ist es dasselbe Verb als *verlaufen*?

Answer (score 1):

Wenn etwas *schmilzt* oder *zerschmilzt,* ändert sich dessen Aggregatszustand dauerhaft von *fest* zu *flüssig*. Das heißt, ein Eiswürfel wird in der Sonne *schmelzen* und danach flüssiges Wasser sein — ehe man das flüssige Wasser in den Eisschrank tut, wird es nicht wieder fest werden.

Im Gegensatz dazu bezeichnet *zerlaufen* einen Vorgang, bei dem der Gegenstand vorher und nachher den Aggregatszustand *fest* aufweist. Zum Beispiel kann Plastik in der Sonne *zerlaufen,* wenn man es herausholt wird es aber wieder fest, nur die Form ist eine leicht andere.

Eis wird also in der Regel *schmelzen,* es sei denn, es ist draußen so kalt, dass es lediglich *zerläuft* und anschließend wieder gefriert (zum Beispiel zu Eiszapfen). Selbst in diesem letzten Fall könnte man aber auch durchaus *schmelzen* sagen.

Comment: Interessant, dass das Wort *verlaufen* die gleiche Bedeutung haben kann, wie *zerlaufen*. Mir war im obigen Sinne bisher nur letzteres bekannt.

Comment: @biolauri Ich hab auch eigentlich *zerlaufen* sagen wollen. Das kommt davon, wenn man nur mit halben Auge auf seine Antwort schaut … Mich würde *verlaufen* jetzt aber auch nicht sonderlich wundern.

Comment: Das kenne ich! ;) Ich gestehe, dass ich nachgeschaut habe und es [laut Duden ebenso korrekt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verlaufen#Bedeutung3) ist.

Answer (score 1):

"Schmelzen" is to melt or dissolve, using heat. This happens to ice, at 0 Celsius, and metals at higher temperatures.

"Zerlaufen," is to make something "run." Imagine carrying a chocolate in your pocket on a hot day. The heat will (partially) dissolve the chocolate, and make it "run" in your clothes.

Comment: I don't think this answer makes much sense. When the chocolate becomes liquid due to temperature, of course that is an example of "schmelzen", as well.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Chocolate is a less "uniform" substance than e.g. ice. So within a certain temperature range, chocolate will partly melt and partly remain solid, which will give it the "runny" quality.